# Pinescript - Exponential Moving Average Vertical Offset

Tags: pine-script

I'm quite new to Pine Script. How would I go about adding functionality to offset the EMA line vertically (up or down) rather than horizontally (left or right)?

```
study(title="Moving Average Exponential", shorttitle="EMA", overlay=true, resolution="")
len = input(9, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, title="Source")
offset = input(title="Offset", type=input.integer, defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
out = ema(src, len)
plot(out, title="EMA", color=color.blue, offset=offset)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
study(title="Moving Average Exponential with Vertical Offset", overlay=true)

// 10 , 20 , 30 , 50 , 100 ,200
// length = 20
length = input(title='Length', type=integer, defval = 10, minval=10, maxval = 200, step = 10)
offset = input(title='Vertical Offset', type=float, defval = 0, minval=-500, maxval = 500, step = 1)

ema_to_plot = ema(close,length)

// Plot EMA
plot(ema_to_plot, color = orange, linewidth=2 )

// Plot vertical
plot(ema_to_plot+offset, offset=0, color=teal, linewidth=2 )
```